# Play Console - I can see crashes but no stacktraces

Tags: google-play-console, crash-reports

I've never had this issue with the Play Console before. I can see crashes happening in the graph (and some users reported them too), but I do not see any details or stracktraces for them.

How can there be around 40 actual crashes in the past 7 days, but only 3 registered reports in the console in the same time.
[image]

[image]

My only guess is because I'm using the roll-out feature on 75%, so not all users received it yet and Google is withholding the data until it's fully released? Or is it because literally none of the affected users agreed to crash reports being shared?

Comment: Could be the opt-in, yeah, or I suspect Play Console also has some thresholds in place to preserve user privacy, hence they won't show you a stacktrace unless enough users have been affected.

Comment: @Pierre See my answer below for an update if you're interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @Pierre was right with his comment, it seems like after about 2 weeks, I suddenly could see detailed crash reports with stacktraces. But also only for a fraction of *all* visible crashes in the graph. So I'm still not 100% sure.

Overall it really could to be the case that detailed stacktraces are held back until enough users have been affected. Though in my case, one report showed up with 10 users affected, while another affected only 3. But they showed up on the same day.
So it could also very well be that it's dependent on something else.

[image]